# Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/app' When deploying google cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Basically I am trying to have a firebase function simply output values in a document, I have only achieved this locally... but the function won't deploy to the cloud. Below is the function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/firestore');

const firebaseConfig = {
    projectId: "covid-info-bw"
};

const db = firebase
.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
.firestore()

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase! Dawg I am beast");
});


exports.getData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const docRef = db.collection('FunctionTest').doc('Cm38kBYShNnyuLVpizcy');
const getDoc = docRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        return res.send('Not Found')
    } 
        console.log(doc.data());
        return res.send(doc.data());
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
});
```

This is a snippet from the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@firebase/app": "^0.6.1",
  "@firebase/firestore": "^1.14.0",
  "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.7.4",
  "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
 "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0"
},
```

This is the error I am getting from running " firebase deploy --only functions:getData,functions:helloWorld"

```
λ firebase deploy --only functions:getData,functions:helloWorld

=== Deploying to 'covid-info-bw'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint

> functions@ lint M:\VueAdventures\covid-info-bw\functions
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (41.45 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: current functions in project: getData(us-central1), helloWorld(us-central1)
i  functions: uploading functions in project: helloWorld(us-central1), getData(us-central1)
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function getData(us-central1)...
!  functions[getData(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
 Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded. 
 Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
 Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    !      functions[helloWorld(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
  Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
 Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
 Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)


 Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        getData
        helloWorld


 To try redeploying those functions, run:
     firebase deploy --only functions:getData,functions:helloWorld


 To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
     firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not supposed to use the Firebase client SDKs for backend code.  What you're trying to do can be achieved using only the Google Cloud Firestore SDK (@google-cloud/firestore) or the Firebase Admin SDK (firebase-admin, which just writes the Cloud SDK).  Just remove the Firebase client SDKs (beginning with @firebase) and use only the backend SDKs you prefer.

Comment: Thank you... i got it to deploy and working fine but locally I get the credentials error... i was wondering how to clear that up?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question with code that doesn't work the way you expect.  First be sure to do a web search for that message, as it's fairly common.